# Perform action after Clear Data of my application

Tags: android

I want to be notified when the user or any other application Clear the data of my application (e.g. User click on `Clear data` button from app info). Is there is any way to know that this action was taken.

I expect to find `Broadcast` intent that I can receive to handle my action! is it possible? IF not are there any other way to know or not?

Answer (score 2):

> I expect to find Broadcast intent that I can receive to handle my action!

[There is one, but your app cannot receive it](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_DATA_CLEARED). Presumably, this is to prevent malware from trying to interfere with this process somehow. If the user wants your data to be cleared, please allow it.

> IF not are there any other way to know or not?

IMHO, an app should be idempotent with respect to application data. In other words, the app should treat a fresh installation identically as it would treat starting up for the first time after its application data has been cleared, which would also be identical to the app having been uninstalled and later reinstalled. Any other behavior either has privacy ramifications (e.g., trying to use some device-specific identifier and record whether the app had been installed here before) or clutter ramifications (e.g., storing some file on common external storage and checking for its existence when your app realizes that it has no application data on internal or its portion of external storage).